# Is it possible to test that a MediatR request has been registered?

Tags: c#, .net, mediatr

I use MediatR in my solution which has several projects and each project generates a single EXE. Each EXE is registering different MediatR requests (i.e. `IRequest`), some from a common project, some from the EXE project itself. The problem I encountered is that I forgot to register an assembly and although all the unit tests were green, executing the program didn't work because it could not find some requests.

What I'd like to do is a unit test that validates that all the required requests are properly registered in my program.

My goal would be to do something like that:

```cs
var myApp = MyApp.Create();

var request = myApp.Host.Services.GetService<MyRequest>();  // this obviously doesn't work...
Assert.That(requests, Is.Not.Null);                         // but it's to see what I'd like to be able to test
```